# Cross referencing assemblies

Tags: .net, circular-reference, project-reference, cross-reference

I have three projects in my .net solution.
The main project and two class library projects.

I have found out that I need to cross reference the class library projects.
**Can I do that?** Is it safe or there are some considerations?

Comment: Define "Cross reference the class library projects".  If you mean Class Library A needs to refer to Class Library B and B needs to refer to A, then yes that is problematic and smacks of bad design

Comment: You won't be able to do that .. VS will complain ..

Comment: exactly, why problematic.  
can you explain or refer to a resource explainging why.
thanks

Comment: There are a few posts on StackOverflow about circular references or circular dependencies.  Here's a good one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308915/why-are-circular-references-in-visual-studio-a-bad-practice

Comment: Madhur Ahuja  you'r right, VS won't allow me to do so  thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The IDE won't let you when the projects are in one solution.  There are subtle ways to confuzzle it.  But then the solution cannot be built from scratch (i.e. Build + Rebuild) since the assembly reference isn't available yet.  Refactor this, you probably want a 3rd assembly that both can reference.

Answer (score 3):

Circular references are *possible* (via the command-line and some tricks; not via the IDE) but are a major pain; don't do it!

Either add an *extra* assembly for the common types, or merge the two libraries.

In many ways, fewer is simpler... A myriad of dlls doesn't mean that you have achieved purity - it is just a mess.

Answer (score 2):

When I have run into this problem, I have **created classes that only have properties.** Could be `Employee`, `Customer`, `Product`, whatever. Those classes don't need to reference any other project, so multiple projects can reference them.

The methods that belong to those objects (`Employee`, `Customer`, `Product`) then go into their own classes in the other projects.

One situation where I have encountered this quite often is in a three-layered application - presentation layer, business layer, and data access layer. I want the DAL to retrieve data and populate an Employee object, which is returned to the BLL. If the Employee class is in the BLL and has both properties and methods, then there is no easy way to populate an Employee object in the DAL and return it to the BLL -- because the BLL must have a reference to the DAL, so the DAL cannot in turn reference the BLL. Creating the separate project with properties-only classes (`Employee`, `Customer`, `Product`) is one way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

If by "cross reference", you mean that you want to do the following:

1) Project **MAIN** contains references to **LIBRARY-ALPHA** and **LIBRARY-BETA**

2) Project **LIBRARY-ALPHA** contains references to **LIBRARY-BETA**

3) Project **LIBRARY-BETA** contains references to **LIBRARY-ALPHA**

then no.  Visual Studio will be unable to build **MAIN** until it builds **ALPHA** and **BETA**.  It will be unable to build **ALPHA** until it builds **BETA**.  And it will be unable to build **BETA** until it builds **ALPHA**.  Therefore, it will be unable to build anything.