# Why add a project to a solution rather than a folder?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, architecture, projects-and-solutions, solution

I'm encountering a weird solution structure in my company—the different layers of the application are organized in folders (instead of in projects).

For instance, there are *folders* within the solution named "DAL", "BL", "WCFClient," etc. I've never seen that before, but can't quite put my finger on what troubles me about it.

Can anyone tell me if there are any cons (or possibly pros) for this folder-based organizational approach?

Comment: Projects contain code that compiles into an assembly. Folders are used to keep the solution clearly structured. One application layer does not necessarily mean one project. Who says a DA, BL or Service Layer must be implemented in one single assembly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are few cons and pros for C# (.NET) projects:

**Pros:**

- Multiple projects can cause circular reference problems if classes are not put into correct assemblies. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reference and
  [Why are circular references in Visual Studio a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308915/why-are-circular-references-in-visual-studio-a-bad-practice)
- Multiple projects leads to multiple dll files. Handling those MIGHT be tricky if they are piling up a lot. For instance we had ~200 files in our project and TeamCity sometimes lost few files at build process. We got around of it by zipping our files before deploying them.

**Cons:**

- Code is not modular. You cant reuse parts of it in other projects. I think this is one of biggest downsides. For instance if you want to use one class from assembly. You have to add reference to whole project.
- One project can grow HUGE and cause multiple problems. Starting from name collisions (In VB.NET there are no namespaces automatically created for folders) into deep folder trees.
- Searching from huge project is harder than from small one (depending how accurate the foldering is)

Comment: *"Multiple projects leads to multiple dll files"* - only if your target output is a DLL file. *"Code is not modular. You cant reuse parts of it in other projects"* - on what basis do you draw this conclusion? Projects are a Microsoft-specific build feature. Developers manage to achieve modularity in C++ perfectly fine without Visual Studio.

Comment: But when files are in folders, there aren't name collisions, because they are in different namespaces, and you CAN use files in those folders from different folders :-)  What am I missing here? :-)

Comment: Well based on WCFClient folder I thought this is .NET project. Its well noticed that language ain't mentioned in question. 

On that modular comment I'm trying to say that if you are having one assembly (project) and you want to use one class from that assembly. You have to add reference to whole project.

Comment: It is. NET, and you are right. Just didn't get it the first time :-)

Comment: You are right about collission in C#. In VB folders don't cause namespace changes automatically. Can you clarify the language what you are using.

Comment: Is it really a big deal referencing a big project though?

Comment: Short answer yes.
Long answer: Referring big projects will increase your application size and build times (of course if you are referring only DLL then there is no build time problem, but using own products as dll reference is rare and slows down a development). Searching of code is also slower (if using project references) and huge projects are more likely to cause circular reference problem.

Of course if you add only one huge project it won't cause problems :).